# grep / regex - single comma on a line

Tags: regex, grep

How would you grep through a set of files looking for any file that has a comma on a line by itself with this caveat. I want it to test true if the comma has whitespace characters before or after it.

Comment: How would **you** do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for a single comma character on a line, surrounded by optional whitespace is:

```
/^\s*,\s*$/
```

Comment: This will match a comma with no whitespace.